# Python - early return from exec

Tags: python

I know that some consider Python's `exec` and `eval` functions evil. I do not mind. I have different problem. Suppose that I have a script stored in a string and I want to execute it using function `exec(my_script_as_string)`. Suppose that at some point in the script, e.g. based on certain condition I need to return from that script. How to do that? Command `return` is not for this for sure. Function quit() not only quits the script inside my `exec()` but also the outer script that called the `exec`. `sys.exit` is the same. So... how to do this? Is is even possible?

Example, which does not work:

```
print('A')
exec("print('B');quit();print('C')")
print('D')
```

My desired output would be:

```
A
B
D
```

but it is

```
A
B
```

I know that the script could always be rearranged so that there are many if/else clauses that will problably eliminate the need to exit early, but sometimes it is quite complicated especially when combined with cycles...

Comment: If you plan to only do `print('B')`, then escape the `exec(...) ` function....why not just omit `quit();print('C')`?

Comment: @MohammadS. Presumably in the real code it's a conditional exit.

Comment: @MohammadS. Of course, this example is just simplified version of the real script which is much more complicated.

Comment: may I ask why you need so much exec ?

Comment: @ Xavier: because I need a part of the application to be scriptable - so that the user can tweak certain calculation process a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to create a function within the `exec` that you then call, that way you could use `return`, for example:

```
exec("""
def _f():
    print('B')
    return
    print('C')
_f()
""")
```

Comment: Oh, this looks clever and solves the problem. So simple and elegant, How come I did not think of it myself. Thanks!